# tikzpicture behind text

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, pgflayers

Is there a way to push a tikzpicture behind text?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% -- packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

% -- indeces highlight
\newcommand{\xhl}[1][x]{
  \rcolor{red!50}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\yhl}[1][y]{
  \rcolor{blue!50}{#1}
}

% -- document
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \tikznode{start}{a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[1]}} & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[n]}\\
      a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}\\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
      a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & \tikznode{end}{a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}}\\
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}

  % -- TikZ part
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
      \draw[-, line width=5mm, cap=round, green, opacity=0.35] (start.north west) -- (end.south east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I get is

[image]

But what I would like to have is the green line being behind the matrix elements.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes. But your code is not all compilable. If it was, you could use `atbegshi` or `eso-pic` to add this on the background. Nowadays one can use the `nicematrix` package to obtain such results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make the shading *appear* to be on the background is to use `blend mode = multiply`. This is the method suggested by the `nicematrix` manual, which allows one to produce nice(r) matrices.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
% -- indeces highlight
\newcommand{\xhl}[1][x]{%
  \textcolor{red!50}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\yhl}[1][y]{%
  \textcolor{blue!50}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A matrix}

\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}
    a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[2]} & \Cdots & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[n]}\\
    a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[2]} & \Cdots & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}\\
    \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots\\
     a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[2]} & \Cdots & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}
\CodeAfter
  \tikz [blend mode=multiply]
    \draw[-, line width=6mm, cap=round, green, opacity=0.35]
          ([xshift=1ex]1-1.north west) -- ([xshift=-1ex]4-4.south east);
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This method works great for black texts but isn't spotless for colored texts as in this question. So her is a compilable version of your code with the annotation in the background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
% -- indeces highlight
\newcommand{\xhl}[1][x]{
  \textcolor{red!50}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\yhl}[1][y]{
  \textcolor{blue!50}{#1}
}

% -- document
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \tikzmarknode{start}{a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[1]}} & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[n]}\\
      a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}\\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
      a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & \tikzmarknode{end}{a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}}\\
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \draw[-, line width=5mm, cap=round, green, opacity=0.35]
      ([xshift=0.5ex]start.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5ex]end.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For beamer you do not need `eso-pic`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% -- indeces highlight
\newcommand{\xhl}[1][x]{%
  \textcolor{red!50}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\yhl}[1][y]{%
  \textcolor{blue!50}{#1}
}

% -- document
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}

\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \draw[-, line width=5mm, cap=round, green, opacity=0.35]
      ([xshift=0.5ex]start.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5ex]end.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A matrix}

  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \tikzmarknode{start}{a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[1]}} & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[n]}\\
      a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}\\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
      a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & \tikzmarknode{end}{a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}}\\
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Another test}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me: the green highlight disappears. Perhaps it's because the actual code (from which I made the MWE) is in a Beamer frame?

Comment: Please accept my sincere apologies - the actual code is a part of a big project with many files that define a lot of things. I tried to clear the code as much as possible, but I assumed (incorrectly) that the MWE should work without testing it. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Ha, I found this question and your answer again, almost exactly 2 years since I asked it - and it helped me this time too. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With the version 5.16 (2021-06-20) of `nicematrix`, it's possible to create such picture without transparency.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
% -- indeces highlight
\newcommand{\xhl}[1][x]{%
  \textcolor{red!50}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\yhl}[1][y]{%
  \textcolor{blue!50}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A matrix}

\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}
\CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
  \tikz 
    \draw[-, line width=6mm, cap=round, green!35]
          ([xshift=1ex]1-1.north west) -- ([xshift=-1ex]4-4.south east);
\Body
    a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[2]} & \Cdots & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[n]}\\
    a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[2]} & \Cdots & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}\\
    \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots\\
     a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[2]} & \Cdots & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a savebox and put the entire matrix inside the tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% -- packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

% -- indeces highlight
\newcommand{\xhl}[1][x]{
  \textcolor{red!50}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\yhl}[1][y]{
  \textcolor{blue!50}{#1}
}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt](#1){$#2$};}}

% -- document
\begin{document}
\savebox{\tempbox}{$\begin{pmatrix}
      \tikznode{start}{a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[1]}} & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & a_{\xhl[1]\yhl[n]}\\
      a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[2]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}\\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
      a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[1]} & a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[2]} & \cdots & \tikznode{end}{a_{\xhl[n]\yhl[n]}}\\
    \end{pmatrix}$}

  % -- TikZ part
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (P) {\usebox\tempbox};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \draw[-, line width=5mm, cap=round, green, opacity=0.35] (start.north west) -- (end.south east);
      %\draw[-, line width=5mm, cap=round, green, opacity=0.35] (P.north west) -- (P.south east);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]